# Min/max grouping using separate timestamp columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with overlapping timespans that looks like this:

```
                   min                 max  grp
0  2013-06-19 18:49:37 2013-06-19 18:49:37    1
0  2013-06-19 18:49:37 2014-07-26 13:56:24    1
1  2013-07-16 03:05:57 2013-07-17 13:11:57    2
2  2013-08-01 03:26:35 2013-08-01 03:26:35    3
1  2013-08-19 06:20:32 2013-08-20 02:32:19    4
3  2013-08-19 07:04:34 2013-08-20 02:01:36    4
2  2013-09-14 09:08:47 2017-06-19 20:11:32    5
4  2013-09-14 22:11:48 2013-09-15 02:14:49    5
5  2013-10-13 21:51:21 2013-10-13 21:51:21    6
6  2013-10-14 03:41:18 2013-10-15 03:17:31    6
3  2013-10-15 03:17:31 2013-10-15 03:17:31    6
7  2013-10-15 04:07:45 2013-10-15 04:07:45    6
8  2013-11-03 07:03:55 2013-11-03 07:03:55    7
9  2013-11-22 02:06:16 2013-11-22 02:06:16    8
10 2013-11-22 02:31:07 2013-11-22 02:31:07    8
```

My objective is to get the min of the `min` and the max of the `max` for each group `grp`.  I have tried:

`df.groupby(['grp'])['min'].agg(['min','max']).reset_index()`

But this only groups by the min and max of `min`, whereas I am looking for the min of `min` and max of `max` per group.

For example, after aggregation, grp 6 should have a min of `2013-10-13 21:51:21` and a max of `2013-10-15 04:07:45`

Is there a simple solution for this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('grp').agg({'min': min, 'max': max})
```